# What happens to colloidal particles in a liquid medium? And how to stabilize it?

Tags: biochemistry, homework

> **Definition**
>
> > Colloid is a dispresion of small particles of one material in another.
>
> **Definition 2 ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colloid))**
>
> > A colloidal system consists of two separate phases: a dispersed phase (or internal phase) and a continuous phase (or dispersion medium) in which the colloid is dispersed. A colloidal system may be solid, liquid, or gas.

I am trying to answer [problem 2](http://tenttiarkisto.fi/exams/8046.1.pdf):

> **Question**
>
> *"Colloidal particles: What are colloidal systems, give an example, what happens to colloidal particles in a liquid medium. How to stabilize colloidal systems in a liquid medium."*

My [lecture slides](https://noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi/tfy-125.2013/luennot/Tfy-125_2013_kolloidit.pdf) mention this about gel: *"a continuous network extending throughout the sample formed by association of colloidal particles or molecules in a liquid", "formed in concentrated polymer solutions" and "formed by association of sol-gel particles"*. Next lecture slides is about "liquid crystals", now I am confused -- not sure whether gel or "liquid crystals" is something to look here.

Comment: ...I think I solved this but I feel it can be useful for future random walkers and do not hesitate to comment whether I have misunderstood something or there is something to add about my trial, is it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"Colloidal particles: What are colloidal systems, give an example,--"**

> Milk, bear foam, paste, blood, ---

**"what happens to colloidal particles in a liquid medium."**

> I understand the q as solid in liquid so a gel. Examples about gel are `"agar, gelatin, jelly and opal"` according to my lecture slides. The electrostatic forces are in some sort of middle phase: not enough to repulse into liquid form but not strong enough to form liquid either.

**"How to stabilize colloidal systems in a liquid medium."**

> **Wikipedia about stability** ([here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colloid))
>
> > *"The stability of a colloidal system is the capability of the system
> >     to remain as it is. Stability is hindered by aggregation and by
> >     sedimentation phenomena, that determine phase separation."*
>
> Now different things to consider are:
>
> - Electrostatic stabilization
>
> > *"In a stable colloid, mass of a dispersed phase is so low that its buoyancy or kinetic energy is too weak to overcome the electrostatic
> >     repulsion between charged layers of the dispersing phase."*
>
> - steric stabilization
>
> > *"particles in polymers which prevents the particle to get close in the range of attractive forces."*